# Authenticate users with OAuth 2 in a Vaadin 8 web app?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, vaadin, vaadin8

With [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) 8 being released and so much of the framework’s API changing, I wonder:

- Is [OAuth 2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) still the modern way to access 3rd-party authentication services such as "Sign-in" with Google, Facebook, Microsoft, etc. ?
- If so, does Vaadin 8 support such authentication services?

I am looking only for authenticating users logging into my Vaadin 8 web app, no authorization needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly Vaadin or Vaadin 8 related question, but I gave my two cents: OAuth 2's status haven't changed because of Vaadin 8 release, and Vaadin 7 and Vaadin 8 allow both OAuth 2 integration - as I know there isn't official support, but this shouldn't prevent you using OAuth 2 with Vaadin.

Comment: For vaadin 7 there exists this addon. https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/oauth2-popup-add-on, since you have the source you should also be able to modify it to work with vaadin 8

Comment: Oauth2 popup add on might have problems with some setups due to push requirement. We had problems with Vaadin 7 (we use jetty & wildfly), and those problems prevented us from using push. Vaadin 8 contains different push libraries, and these problems might have been solved there, but I haven't tested this.